# Get python version

Tags: python

I've installed multiple `Blender` versions on my System an therefore have multiple `python` executables. How can I find out which `python` binary is indeed executing the script when i click `Run Script` in `Blender` embeded script editor? Is there a way to check it inside a script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Sorry downvoted. Can easily be googled.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Scripting* Workspace, there is the Python Console. It shows the current Python Version in the first line:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check the version by importing package “sys” and accessing “sys.version” :

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```